# merge geom_labels color grouped into one

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the data below:

```
DT <- data.frame(x_ = c('1','2','3', '4'), y_ = c('okokok', 'okokok', 'okokok', 'yes'), 
                 group_ = c('a','a','a','b'))
DT
#    x_     y_ group_
# 1   1 okokok      a
# 2   2 okokok      a
# 3   3 okokok      a
# 4   4    yes      b
```

With the resulting plot:

```
ggplot(DT) +
  geom_label(aes(x = x_, y = 'dummy', label = y_, fill = group_, group = group_))
```

[image: plot]

As you can see, the labels for items 1, 2 and 3 are equal. How can I merge this label into only one label that covers 1, 2 and 3 as showed in the example below (sorry for the terrible figure)? Or any sugestions of a ggplot extension that do this kind of graphic?

[image: wanted plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the width of labels is not available as an aesthetic. Nor is it fixed in relation to plot size. This isn't really what `geom_label` is for. You can certainly achieve the effect you are looking for with a combination of `geom_rect` and `geom_text`, but it will be difficult to generalize the result to your real data:

```r
DT %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_label(data = DT, 
             aes(x = x_, y = 'dummy', label = y_, fill = group_, group = group_)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0.75, xmax = 3.25, ymin = 0.97, ymax = 1.03),
            color = "black", fill = "#F8766D") +
  geom_text(aes(x = 2, y = 1, label = "okokok"), check_overlap = TRUE)
```

[image]